# javascript function rotate element => trying to set an IF condition for a specific parameter passed in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to rotate 2 div blocks, one clockwise and the other one CCW.
I already have the first one set, and with `var STEP` I can choose which direction by giving it positive/negative values. Now since I already know the ID of the 2nd div parameter `startUpProc('fourSquares3')`, I tried to create an if statement that checks if the parameter  'fourSquares3' is passed and set the global var STEP to an opposite value (let's say positive in this case) and it's just not working, even with the if , at the end when I run it, they both turn the same way.

So my question is: how can I properly change the code so that if a specific parameter is passed, it wil turn the CCW.

**This is my code:**

```
startUpProc('fourSquares');


var STEP = -7;

function startUpProc(id)
{
    var log = window.document.getElementById(id);
    makeCircle(log, 0);
}

function makeCircle(item, targetAngle) {
    changeRotate(item, targetAngle);

    if (targetAngle < 720) {
        setTimeout(function (){
            makeCircle(item, targetAngle + STEP);
        }, 80);
    }
}

function changeRotate(item, val)
{
    item.style.transform = "rotate(" + val + "deg)";
    item.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + val + "deg)";
    item.style.mozTransform = "rotate(" + val + "deg)";
    //alert(item.style.transform);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use CSS class instead of ID to determine which type of rotation should be applied

Comment: What do you mean "parameter is passed"

Comment: @MarkPerera Hi, startUpProc('fourSquares'); => the string fourSquares is the paramter passed

Comment: Do you use the same function (`startUpProc`) to rotate multiple divs? If so, it explains the cause of issue: you use the same variable (`STEP`) which value is **shared** among multiple divs. Global variable is wrong choice in this case. You have to use a closure or class to encapsulate such data.

Comment: Try using 2 `STEP` values (`step1` and `step2`)

Comment: @MarkPerera I believe I already tried that and other instances, would you be able to put an example that actually works?

Comment: @hindmost - can you give me a working example? I vote correct answer on code that works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you use ***the same*** variable (`STEP`) which value is ***shared*** between two blocks (divs). You have to encapsulate this variable into the code doing rotation. The easiest way to do it is use [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

In your case you have to place declaration of `STEP` as well as all subroutine functions which use it inside `startUpProc` function. This ensures that each instance (call) of `startUpProc` will deal with its own instance of variable.
Furthermore it is better to determine type of direction by CSS class, not by ID. This makes your code more flexible, not dependent on fixed ID values. Also it allows to use this code for multiple blocks (3 and more), not only for two as in your example.

```
var classCcw = 'ccw'; // class indicating counter-clockwise direction

function startUpProc(id)
{
    var log = window.document.getElementById(id);
    var isCcw = (' '+log.className+' ').indexOf(' '+classCcw+' ') >= 0;
    var STEP = isCcw? 7 : -7;
    makeCircle(log, 0);

    function makeCircle(item, targetAngle) {
        changeRotate(item, targetAngle);

        if (targetAngle < 720) {
            setTimeout(function (){
                makeCircle(item, targetAngle + STEP);
            }, 80);
        }
    }

    function changeRotate(item, val)
    {
        item.style.transform = "rotate(" + val + "deg)";
        item.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + val + "deg)";
        item.style.mozTransform = "rotate(" + val + "deg)";
        //alert(item.style.transform);
    }
}

startUpProc('square1');
startUpProc('square2');
startUpProc('square3');
```

HTML code sample:

```
<div id="square1" class="ccw">
<div id="square2">
<div id="square3" class="ccw">
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your call to the function will use the same instance of your varible STEP,
If you change it, they will all change.

If you want diffrent directions you must seperate it,
Something like this:

```
function makeCircle(item, targetAngle) {
    changeRotate(item, targetAngle);
    var direction = 1;
    //condition 
    if (item=='whatver') 
      direction = -1;
    if (targetAngle < 720) {
        setTimeout(function (){
            makeCircle(item, targetAngle + STEP * direction);
        }, 80);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I actually used this but it doesn't work. Any chance for a quick fiddle with 2 div boxes showing how this change works? Toda Ziv.